# Why is my else tag in django template not working

Tags: python, html, django-models

So i have manytomany field .In the template i want to verify if the current user exist in the manytomany field and display an out put respectively

model.py

```
  class Business(models.Model):
      businessname=models.CharField(max_length=230,null=True)
      creator==models.ForeignKey(User,unique=True)
      users=models.ManyToManyField(Users,null=True,related-name="shared")
```

In my veiw.py

```
def Display(request):
    BusinessObjects = Business.objects.all()
    template="template.html"
    return render(request,template,context={'objects':BusinessObjects})
```

template.html

```
<div class="allobjects">
 {% for obj in objects %}
 {{obj.businessname}}
 <!-- verify if the  current login user exist in the many to many field-->
 {% for currentuser in obj.users %}
  {% if user.username in currentuser.username %}
   <p> You are sharing this object</p>
  {% else %}
  <p> You are not sharing this object

 {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
 {% endfor %}
</div>
```

My else statement does not work despite the username is not present .But the first statement execute if username present .What i my doing wrong in the if statement and why is my else statement not working .Thanks .And please do not downgrade my question if it is not important to you.

Answer (score 0):

Per Django's documentation, an empty value resolves to "nothing" rather than causing an error.  So, it might be both values are resolving to nothing:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/language/

```
{% if user.username in currentuser.username %}
```

If they both are empty it should resolve to true.

**EDIT**
The actual issue here is that you're using "in" as your comparative operator rather than "==".  If the username is missing you're checking if an empty string is contained within a given string (which it is - kind of like 0 elements is a subset of any set of elements).

If you want to filter out empty strings you can use the length tag.  From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#length):

```
length¶
Returns the length of the value. This works for both strings and lists.

For example:

{{ value|length }}
If value is ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] or "abcd", the output will be 4.

The filter returns 0 for an undefined variable.

{% if user.username|length > 0 %}
```

Comment: So what is the solution and the right way to do it ?

Comment: Ah, it's because you're using "in" rather than "==".  Technically an "empty string" is always contained "within" a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
{% if not user in obj.users.all%}
 {% else %}
 {% endif %}
```